# How to check if mongodb replica is already configured through shell script?

Tags: bash, mongodb

I have configured mongodb replica set in three of the nodes through a shell script. When I again run the script, it should check if replica is already configured and should not configure the replica again. How can I check the same through shell script?

Comment: Did you try the command?

Comment: When you want to make sure that the replica is already configured on any box and should not be configured again, basically you should just be checking whether it's running. If it's running, then that should suffice. Anyways, what error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this command and then check its return status:

```
mongo target_host:port/db_name --eval "db.stats()"
```

I was checking on my local machine itself so i used 127.0.0.1. If you do not specify a database, the mongo shell for your session will use the *test* database by default. Since i too connected to test db, so i skipped that thing in my command given below:

```
mongo 127.0.0.1:27119 --eval "db.stats()" > /dev/null 2>&1

result=$?

if [ $result -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "Mongo replica set running!"
else
    echo "Mongo replica set not running!"
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: how can I specify db name ?? There may be many dbs inside my replica set.

Comment: As i mentioned in the command above, you can specify db name just after the `port/` string. It should not matter how many dbs the replica set contains. Your concern, if i got it correct, is to check whether the replica set is configured, correct? I have taken the liberty to assume that you mean to check whether it's running. Let me know if that's not the case. As long as you are receiving a success response from any db (in my example, test db), it should suffice. `mongo target_host:port/db_name --eval "db.stats()"`

Comment: Also, just to be explicit, port 27119 is just an example. You need to specify the port that _you_ have configured for your replica set.

Comment: This doesn't have to do much with the question, however, I wish to tell you that relying on `$?` during if statements is an anti-pattern, as the reason if exists is to do command return code checks. So instead of using `$?`, I would recommend running the command directly into the if statement directly, like so: `if mongo 127.0.0.1:27119 --eval "db.stats()" > /dev/null 2>&1`

Comment: Agree. That's indeed a better way to check. Please feel free to edit. :)